# How can I extract a YouTube URL from its JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, perl, url, youtube

Hello I would like to know if my script is good; I want to have the full URL as the outcome of my Perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1');

my $get = $ua->get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko0c4QT5aVA')->content;
if ($get =~ m,(.*?)http:(.*?)\"\)\;\yt.preload.start\(\"(.*?)\"\)\;</script>,sgi){

    print "First:$2\n\n";

    print "Second:$3\n";
```

Comment: Can you show us what do you expect as output ? What's wrong ? Don't sure I understand.

Comment: this is the wrong output : http:\/\/o-o.preferred.tm-jhb1.v8.lscache3.c.youtube.com\/generate_204?sparams=algorithm%2Cburst%2Ccp%2Cfactor%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Csource%2Cexpire\u0026algorithm=throttle-factor\u0026itag=34\u0026ip=118.0.0.0\u0026burst=40\u0026sver=3\u0026signature=D0F09C289697E56E0756C2518CE0FC02FAAD063C.CE71F74FE8B8935A4B416C714F26EE4284F0264E\u0026source=youtube\u0026expire=1332708216\u0026key=yt1\u0026ipbits=8\u0026factor=1.25\u0026cp=U0hSR1dLVl9GUENOMl9PRVpDOnNoT3dWUzR5R19t\u0026id=35819a7b64b3ddb

Comment: i'm looking for this : http://o-o.preferred.tm-jhb1.v18.lscache4.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cexpire&fexp=917000&itag=43&ip=115.0.0.0&signature=380CD5BA9BF70333B407901EC159F8AC72B45017.7F071766B3E06D61340827959227B3CF12F5362B&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&expire=1332660096&key=yt1&ipbits=8&cp=U0hSR1ZRTl9OUENOMl9OS1JBOnczXzJaNWtkZmpD&id=08b36c883323283c

Comment: Why on Earth would you ever use commas as the expression delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it better ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1');

my $get = $ua->get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko0c4QT5aVA')->content;
if ($get =~ m,(.*?)http:(.*?)\"\)\;\yt.preload.start\(\"(.*?)\"\)\;</script>,sgi){
    my $out = $3;
    $out =~ s@\\/@/@g;
    $out =~ s@\\u0026@\&@g;
    print "$out\n";
}
```

Comment: really appreciate the fast help over here, sorry for the late response but thnx, i will recommend everyone to here :)

Answer (score 3):

I really appreciate [Mojo::UserAgent](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent)'s built in DOM features for this sort of thing. You can pull out exactly the script that you want (too bad YouTube doesn't attach `id`s to them):

```
use v5.10;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $script = Mojo::UserAgent->new->
    get("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko0c4QT5aVA" )->
    res->
    dom->
    find('script')->
    [1];

my( $yt_preload_start ) = $script =~ m|;\s*yt\Q.preload.start(\E\s*"(.*?)"|;
$yt_preload_start =~ s{\\(.)}{$1}g;
$yt_preload_start =~ s{u0026}{&}g;

say "URL is $yt_preload_start";
```

I would have preferred a JavaScript parser to pull out the argument for `yt.preload.start`, but I don't have experience with any of those.

Comment: You can also pass arguments directly to dom - dom('script') - the find is implied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear from your question and your code what you are trying to extract from the HTML. In particular, why are you capturing everything before the main part of the match and then ignoring the capture?

My best guess is that you want all the URLs thta appear as parameters to the `yt.preload.start` JavaScript function. You can do that like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI::Escape;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.1');
my $html = $ua->get('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko0c4QT5aVA')->content;

my @urls = $html =~ /\Qyt.preload.start("\E(http[^"]+)/gi;
print map uri_unescape($_)."\n", @urls;
```

**edit:**

This solution leaves the URLs with JavaScript Unicode characters `"\u0026"`, which is the same as Perl `"\N{N+0026}"`, or an ampersand `"&"`. Also the string starts with `"http:\/\/"`. Correcting these is straightforward. One way is to replace the final `map` with

```
print map {
  my $ss = uri_unescape $_;
  $ss =~ s/\\u0026/&/g, $ss =~ s|\\/|/|g;
  $ss;
} @urls;
```

Comment: Borodin, what does mean `\Q` and `\E` in the regex ? Any reference to a doc ?

Comment: @sputnick: they are very helpful, you should learn them.  As the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) say, `\Q: quote non-word characters till \E`.  For more information, see info on [quotemeta](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

Comment: I have used `/\Qyt.preload.start("\E/` to leave the regex readable while escaping the dots and parenthesis. It would otherwise look like `/yt\.preload\.start\("/`